# How to have permalink like domain.com/%category%/%postname%/

Tags: permalinks

As the title says, I want to have a permalink structure like

```
domain.com/%category%/%postname%/
```

When I save this structure, no change is do.
Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Permalinks`. Select `Custom Structure` and enter `/%category%/%postname%/` in edit field. Save. That's all.

Comment: It does nothing ! no effet with the url even Wordpress notice success operation !

Comment: Show me the whole line of 'Custom Structure'.

Comment: I should edit it first to another structure such a default structure, then use your permalink suggest... Now it works ! thanks